# Mysql database change ordering of records

Tags: mysql

Here I have data in mysql database that is reversed in order. How to change the ordering so that default ordering that is ASC is reversed. 
Primary field is ID. ANd ID is auto_increment. I need to change the ID fields in reverse order for each records.

For example. Let's assume I have 2 records in table.

```
ID  field
1   field1
2   field2
```

I want to have field2 to have ID 1 and field1 to have ID 2

Comment: It would be great if you show any example :)

Comment: do u want to update the table or the order is just needed  in the select?

Comment: Then you can go with @puggan's answer..

Answer (score 0):

You could do:

```
ALTER TABLE `table` ORDER BY `ID` DESC
```

but its bad database design
its against [First normal form](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Database_normalization)

Comment: i think it moves data around, so if you don't specify any `ORDER BY` and not using a index in you `where`, mysql is going to give you the data in the order that its stored on disk, and after that row thats `ID DESC`

Answer (score 0):

or you can export the entire table in script file. "sql" and once the script in hand you can put in order all the (INSERT INTO) backwards. It takes a few minutes but it works

1: generate script from your base..you can use phpmyadmin or console line mysql
2. reverse the insert command

Base script Before:

```
INSERT INTO example (name, age) VALUES('Sandy Smith', '21' )
INSERT INTO example (name, age) VALUES('peter brad', '38' )
INSERT INTO example (name, age) VALUES('mike alves', '24' )
```

base script After:

```
INSERT INTO example (name, age) VALUES('mike alves', '24' )
INSERT INTO example (name, age) VALUES('peter brad', '38' )
INSERT INTO example (name, age) VALUES('Sandy Smith', '21' )
```

it is a slower but can it clean

OHTER solution ->

You can then try something like this: - Create a new table with the information from the original table by retrieving all the id and reversing with ORDER BY!

```
CREATE TABLE newtable SELECT ID, row1, row2, row3, row4, row5 FROM oldtable ORDER BY id DESC ;
```

And then delete the old table It should work without problem

Comment: You mean change order of data while exporting and import again?

Comment: Yes exactly. Hoping that you did not record miles or you can always write a script faster. However it is the only clean solution with no problem that I found for it.

Comment: I have more than 1000 records

Comment: Ok so i have found another solution for you try this. OHTER solution ->

You can then try something like this: - Create a new table with the information from the original table by retrieving all the id and reversing with ORDER BY!

Comment: I have change my last answer for more informations about this